# Rethinkdb Filter command with secondary index

Tags: rethinkdb

Is it possible to use the filter command with a secondary index? If I have no secondary indexes perform the query:

```
r.db('test').table('first').filter(r.row('col2').eq(8302))
```

Then create a secondary index on 'col2' and rerun the query, it takes the exact same amount of time. I know I can use 'getAll' and pass in an index and it is much faster but was hoping to have the filter command make use of it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RethinkDB currently does not have a query optimizer, so filter will not use a secondary index.

There is an issue to use index by default (like in orderBy - but the same applies for filter) -- https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2356
Feel free to chime in.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it didn't have a query optimizer but I thought there might be an explicit way to tell filter to use the index.